# Delete SDK Message Processing Step from MS CRM Plugin

Tags: c#, .net, dynamics-crm-2013

I faced really strange limitation of the MS Dynamics CRM, that is not covered anywhere in documentation.

It's is possible to create entities of `sdkmessageprocessingstep` type from within plugin, thus subscribing plugin to the events on demand, however it's not possible to perform reverse operation — delete these steps, or at least disable them.

CRM fires exception in case if `Delete` message is called for `sdkmessageprocessingstep`, however the same code works just fine, when executed from command line application for example.

Have anybody faced with the this issue before? What's the reason of it? Do you know any approach how to work around it?

Comment: Can you provide more details? What is the entity and step on which the plugin (that is trying to perform the delete) registered and what is the entity and step of the plugin step being deleted? What is the exception message and is there an inner exception message?

Comment: @Nicknow actually no details, the error message was not descriptive that much. However with the help of Henk van Boeijen I was able to nail down the issue in my code: I was using my own wrapper around `OrganizationService` and it actually have hidden from me fact, that `OrganizationService` was executed from `SYSTEM` user. And apparently `SYSTEM` does not have explicit permissions to delete plugin steps. Once I have changed user to current one, everything worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is indeed possible to delete plugin steps from within plugin code. However, the user must still be authorized to do this.

For sandboxed plugins it is enough to have the appropriate entity privileges.

For plugins registered for full trust mode the user must be a member of the deployment administrator group. Also, the plugin code must be executed on a thread impersonating the Windows account of the administrator. This implies that this only works in an OnPremise environment and within the company network.

Before you delete a plugin step, you may need to delete associated pluginstepimages first.

Comment: OK, so what will be your suggestion to look at, if I'm sure, that I'm deployment administrator and I have all needed permissions (I'm able to perform this operation from command line).

I've also try to execute `OrganizationService` as Administrator, but this actually didn't helped.

Maybe any other thing I could be missing for now?

Comment: Does your step have pluginstep images associated to it? If not, share a few lines of your code and the Exception details.

Comment: Have you checked on `CRM2013` or maybe earlier versions?

Comment: A product I originally designed for Dynamics CRM 4.0 uses this technique. It even registers/unregisters assemblies, plugins, steps and images. It was successfully upgraded to CRM 2011 and continues working perfectly on 2013 and 2015 as well.

Comment: Ok, you gave me hope. Maybe something in environment setup or I missing something...

Comment: Thanks, I found bug. I was using wrapper around service, and it was running on behalf of the `SYSTEM`, not particular user. I switched the identity and all worked.